# Python-Pandas: how to avoid the keyerror while changing the df inplace

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

### Example

Creating test df

```
def f_test_df(n_rows, n_cols):
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(n_rows, n_cols))
    df = df1.applymap(lambda x: round(x*10))
    return df 

np.random.seed(seed=1)
df1 = f_test_df(7, 7)
```

[image]

Now, carrying out an inplace operation that changes the original dataframe itself.

```
df1.drop(columns=[2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
         inplace=True)
```

[image]

If the above line is run again, it would lead to a key error, since the df has changed now. The same is true for all other operations that change the dataframe itself.

The solution is to use a try-except construct, as shown below:

```
try:
    df1.drop(columns=[2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
             inplace=True)
    pass
except:
    pass
```

Now, the earlier keyerror is avoided.

### Question

However, this is not an elegant solution.
Is there a more pythonic way to achieve the same?
How to avoid the `KeyError` when changing the original `df` itself?

Answer (score 4):

[`pd.DataFrame.drop()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) has the `errors` argument:

```
df1.drop(columns=[2,3,4,5,6], inplace=True, errors='ignore')
```

So just specify `errors='ignore'` and it won't throw an error. `errors` default value is `raise`, which would raise a `KeyError` if the columns aren't present.